# In order to see Activities fields in Views - do I need to add/install CiviCRM Entity?

Tags: webform-civicrm, drupal-views, civicrm-entity

I want to add Activities fields or Relationships in Drupal Views. Do I need to add/install CiviCRM Entity?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is No, you do not, at least for Drupal 7. What I was missing was to first, add a new View, selecting CiviCRM Activities, not CiviCRM Contacts. I discovered clues starting on [page 169](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/programming/9781782160441/9/ch09lvl1sec85/designing-campaign-dashboards-in-drupal-views) of [The CiviCRM Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/civicrm-cookbook) by Tony Horrocks.

Comment: yep. thinking through the starting point is half the battle